# SSIS Error when running and receiving data from Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am having two servers; one has SQL Server another one has Oracle. SSIS package is setup to receive data from Oracle into SQL Server.

Trying to figure out the below error.

> OnError,ServerNameAB,Domain\UserID,pkgLoad_Data,{794F09AE-9188-4F94-AC4F-950361612345},{D131842F-59AF-450A-BE1E-3E7EBB812345},3/14/2022 7:26:01 PM,3/14/2022 7:26:01 PM,-1071610805,0x,An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

> OnError,ServerNameAB,Domain\UserID,Data Flow Task,{7c7246a7-64e3-4866-9314-534074112345},{D131842F-59AF-450A-BE1E-3E7EBB812345},3/14/2022 7:26:01 PM,3/14/2022 7:26:01 PM,-1073450974,0x,SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "ADO NET Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (9). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Troubleshooting tried:
rebooting the "receiving data" server
restarting SSMS

update: Below are the correct settings...
[image]

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem like it should be using the Shared Memory Provider to connect from SSIS to the Oracle server. Has the Client Protocols configuration changed in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager on the machine executing the SSIS Packages? i.e.: have the enabled/disabled states for Shared Memory and TCP/IP providers changes? The priority?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning. Thanks for the reply. Yes I have the set as it is. Screenshot attached. even restarting the services in configuration manager does not fix the issue.

Comment: These are client configuration settings (for outgoing connections), so restarting the services won't affect things. Either in the SSIS package connection strings you can use `tcp:serverNameOrIpAddress` to force use of the TCP/IP protocol; or in the Client Protocols here you can change the Order numbers such that the protocols are ranked 1 TCP/IP, 2 Shared Memory, 3 Named Pipes.